# Drawer menu icon disappears after applying a custom view to ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I have a drawer menu icon before adding a custom action bar view, in this custom view, it's a just a imageView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/bell_icon"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/double_spacer"
        android:id="@+id/ic_notif"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and in the fragment that will have this custom view applied, I have the following lines:

```
@Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);

        LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
        View customView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.action_bar_custom_layout, null);

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM|ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME|ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);

        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle(R.string.plan_member_services);
        actionBar.setCustomView(customView);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

        ImageView img_notification = customView.findViewById(R.id.ic_notification);
        img_notif.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                System.out.println("*** icon clicked ***");
            }
        });

        if(isShowIcon){            
            img_notifi.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            img_notifi.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
...
```

With above code, I am able to see the icon of the action bar defined in "AndroidMenifest.xml":

```
<application
        android:name=".MyApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:allowClearUserData="false"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MyActionBarTheme">
```

and also I'm able to see the title, but the menu icon for the drawer menu is gone! What have I missed?

Answer (score 0):

I found when I put those codes in the activity instead of the fragment, the drawer menu icon appears when the fragment loaded.